# How to set index base directory in hibernate full text search dynamically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am trying to implement Hibernate full text search in my project and in this  during login user select database which he/she wants to use. Means using dynamic data source routing. Index base directory path is in hibernate.properties file and it will be different for different database.

So now I want to change it at run time on the basis of selection of database by user. When we are creating session bean in spring then code is reading Hibernate properties. I searched a lot on internet and got an idea to override hibernate.properties file at run time. But I have some doubts:

- How to override it for session factory, not for JPA
- I think I don't need to reinitialize the session factory after overriding property. It will automatically read new directory on overriding .

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search will read properties from all these places:

- the JPA persistence.xml file
- other JPA configuration (e.g. programmatic)
- the Hibernate ORM `hibernate.properties` file
- any other Hibernate ORM properties applying to the `SessionFactory`
- Java System Properties
- Environment variables

In short: don't set the index base in a fixed configuration property but set it dynamically in any way you set the other Hibernate ORM properties.

Comment: Hi Sanne, thanks for your answer. But actually , I want to change index directory at run time of application. In our application we are using abstract data source routing to point application or hibernate to particular database so now according to selected database, we need to use index directory.

Comment: So Sanne, you can think like that we have different index directory for each database and I need to change index directory according to user selection of database. So can we do it or how we can do it.   Can you give one example of how to do with java system properties